# Transparent input text & background with white cursor

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to make input with transparent text color and background; my SCSS code:

```
&_transparent {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This simple code works as I need but there is some problem - cursor is transparent too. How could I fix it in all main browsers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your full code.

Comment: Can you make a snippet showing your problem ? I can't reproduce it with the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.transparent {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="transparent" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.transparent {
opacity:1;
background:transparent;
}
```

In this code the class name is transparent and the text will be not visible since the opacity is maximum.